# Musical notes for single string lead acoustic guitar

Tags: guitar, sheet-music, acoustic-guitar

**Question Edited**
I wrote the guitar strumming notes of a song on a music street on one staff, now I am trying to write the lead notes on another staff. The lead part consists of single string notes. I lead part, may be due the single string composition, don't seem to sound good. Any advice?

As per the inputs of [John Belzaguy](https://music.stackexchange.com/users/67196/john-belzaguy), the edited strumming pattern is listed below:

[image]

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question. The video shows tabulature. What is missing in the video is notation of rhythm. Is that what you're asking about, how to notate rhythm?

Comment: I want to be able to write the lead also in a music sheet so that I can play the strumming and the lead like in a multi track. Presently the representation and timing is based on hearing only. I want to sync with the guitar strumming beats if possible to get the timings right.

Comment: So do I understand, you wish to notate rhythm of your music, and you don't know anything about rhythm notation so far? I'm not sure if this can be answered in a concise manner, but I'm sure someone could provide references to some basic teaching materials...

Comment: I am aware how to write the strumming notation of the music but not sure about the lead  part. Question edited to include the strumming rhythm.

Comment: But there's no difference! You notate eight notes, quarter notes etc. the same way. This video shows notation of tab with rhythm, including solo in the middle https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04xDZj0smHQ Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: What you would normally do would be putting two scores or tabulatures on top of each other, making sure that they are aligned, like in this example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJVlbLK7VbA&list=PLgvWsy0-mt4TFra_ldczTmscbFxlvV_2x Most score/tabulature writing software can do it for you

Comment: @user1079505: I am doing similarly on Guitar Pro. I issue is the lead part isn't coming right theoretically.  If I pick a guitar I am able to do so. It's rather issue representing the lead on the music sheet. Within a bar, trying to make the lead sound right on a music sheet is the issue.

Comment: I see you got the answer you wanted, but one suggestion: get a rhythm practice book and learn notation from playing. Most methods go from simple to more complex rhythms. Something with a CD playalong would probably help a lot. When you can play from reading, then writing rhythms will be much easier. Your issue is not specifically about writing, it's about understanding rhythm notation generally.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis: I agree. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly do you struggle with but I hope I will be able to give you some pointers here.

In this link you can find arrangement to one of the songs you mentioned in comments: https://musescore.com/user/99729/scores/4141356 This is score, not tab, but the rules for rhythm notation are the same.

Let's look at the first couple of measures:
[image]

I marked the beats for you.

1. Note that the melody (upper staff) and the accompaniment (lower staff) have different rhythms. We call them separate *voices*. Sometimes you may have multiple voices written in a single staff, this happens often in classical guitar or fingerstyle repertoire.
2. Note how beats in the melody match those in the accompaniment. So note on beat 4 in the melody is exactly above note on beat 4 in accompaniment.
3. Note that melody starts with *anacrusis* or *pickup notes*, in plain language it starts before beat 1.
4. Note that also there is some graphical flexibility, e.g. the first quarter note in the second measure in the bottom staff takes a bit more space than the others, because there is more activity in the melody there.

I would say counting the beats is the most critical thing to work on. Try to play the accompaniment while counting the beats aloud. Then try doing the same for the melody. And also try playing the accompaniment while singing the melody, and analyze which notes come at the same time.

Comment: I think your answered almost my question. Let me digest your reply . +1 Thanks.

Comment: Wow, the link you have given is exactly what I was looking for. Is the music sheet lead + piano?

Comment: @seccpur This is piano notation for right hand (upper staff) and left hand (lower staff), and I think the right hand is meant to play the same notes as the voice. But music for multiple instruments is notated the same way (except of the brace on the left side indicating both staves are for the same instrument).

Comment: Can it apply on guitar lead as well?

Comment: @seccpur Yes, definitely, accompaniment guitar on one staff and the lead guitar on another.

Comment: Is it fair to conclude that playing instrument is much easier than writing on the score?

Comment: @seccpur This certainly varies case by case. But here I would argue, if writing down the score forces you to understand better what you play, it will help you to perform as well.